# Shutdown bitcoin-qt during reindexing?

Tags: pruning, reindex

I started `bitcoin-qt` with `--reindex` and pruning on.

Can I safely shutdown and restart?

If yes how? Do I have to pass `--reindex` again or will `bitcoin-qt` remember and continue from where it stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I safely shutdown and restart?

Yes.

> If yes how? Do I have to pass `--reindex` again or will `bitcoin-qt` remember and continue from where it stopped?

No, Bitcoin Core will remember that it was reindexing and continue the reindex.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

First I made a backup of `datadir`. Next I started again with `--reindex` and it started from scratch.

Makes sense but I don't want that.

So I replayed backup and start without `--reindex`. It started where it had stopped before.

Andrew, thanks for the quick and helpful response!